# How to change column position in powershell?

Tags: powershell, position

Is there any easy way how to change column position? I'm looking for a way how to move column 1 from the beginning to the and of each row and also I would like to add zero column as a second last column. Please see txt file example below.
Thank you for any suggestions.

File sample

```
TEXT1,02/10/2015,55.930,57.005,55.600,56.890,1890  
TEXT2,02/10/2015,51.060,52.620,50.850,52.510,4935
TEXT3,02/10/2015,50.014,50.74,55.55,52.55,5551
```

Output:

```
02/10/2015,55.930,57.005,55.600,56.890,1890,0,TEXT1  
02/10/2015,51.060,52.620,50.850,52.510,4935,0,TEXT2
02/10/2015,50.014,50.74,55.55,52.55,5551,0,TEXT3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option:

```
#Prepare test file
(@'
TEXT1,02/10/2015,55.930,57.005,55.600,56.890,1890  
TEXT2,02/10/2015,51.060,52.620,50.850,52.510,4935
TEXT3,02/10/2015,50.014,50.74,55.55,52.55,5551
'@).split("`n") |
foreach {$_.trim()} | 
sc testfile.txt

#Script starts here
$file = 'testfile.txt'

(get-content $file -ReadCount 0) |
foreach  {
'{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},0,{0}' -f $_.split(',')
} | Set-Content $file

#End of script

#show results    
get-content $file

02/10/2015,55.930,57.005,55.600,56.890,1890,0,TEXT1
02/10/2015,51.060,52.620,50.850,52.510,4935,0,TEXT2
02/10/2015,50.014,50.74,55.55,52.55,5551,0,TEXT3
```

Comment: Is it possible to read input from file instead of (@' text '@) ?

Comment: The (@' text '@)  bits are taking your sample data and writing it out to a file to demonstrate reading from a file.  The actual working script starts at $file = 'testfile.txt'.  The last Get-Content line retrieves the file contents to show how the data has been re-formatted. I added some comments for clarity.

Comment: Thank you. I really like your code. It looks very simple.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, split on commas, spit the results back minus the first result joined by commas, add a 0, and then add the first result to the end and join the whole thing with commas. Something like:

```
$Input = @"
TEXT1,02/10/2015,55.930,57.005,55.600,56.890,1890
TEXT2,02/10/2015,51.060,52.620,50.850,52.510,4935
TEXT3,02/10/2015,50.014,50.74,55.55,52.55,5551
"@ -split "`n"|ForEach{$_.trim()}

$Input|ForEach{
    $split = $_.split(',')
    ($Split[1..($split.count-1)]-join ','),0,$split[0] -join ','
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works fine but can I instead of predefined string  use text file as a input? Like  $Input = test.txt ? And store output in same file test.txt ?

Comment: Sure, just do `$Input = Get-Content 'C:\Path\To\file.txt'` and then after the last `}` add `| Set-Content C:\Path\To\file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

I created file test.txt to contain your sample data. I Assigned each field a name, "one","two","three" etc so that i could select them by name, then just selected and exported back to csv in the order you wanted.

First, add the zero to the end, it will end up as second last.

```
gc .\test.txt  | %{ "$_,0" } | Out-File test1.txt
```

Then, rearrange order.

```
Import-Csv .\test.txt -Header "one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight" | Select-Object -Property two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,one | Export-Csv test2.txt -NoTypeInformation
```

This will take the output file and get rid of quotes and header line if you would rather not have them.

```
gc .\test2.txt | %{ $_.replace('"','')} | Select-Object -Skip 1 | out-file test3.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that there is no header in txt file and I need to keep it that way. Also your output file adds ' " ' to every record.

Comment: You don't need a header in the text file, that's why I had to give Import-Csv a header array so that select-object would know how to reference the field. If you don't want headers or quotes in the output, just delete them after the output file is created, not a big deal. My input file looks identical to the sample you gave, no altered in any way.